# Issue downloading NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to download NetBeans 8.0. However, in the installer, it is asking me to manually specify the folder the jdk is in as it cannot find it. Currently, it is in my downloads folder but when I specify it, it still can't find it. The jdk on my machine is 12.0.1 so I believe that might be the cause of the issue. If it is, can you tell me how to fix it and download the version of NetBeans that supports jdk 12.0.1?

I've tried downloading it on my admin account and restarting the launcher but it still doesn't work

Comment: The default install location on windows is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans 8.0 is not compatible with JDK 12.0.1. NetBeans 8.0 is only compatible with JDK 8 and lower versions not with higher versions. But there is **Apache NetBeans**. Apache NetBeans is compatible with higher versions from JDK 9 to JDK 12. You can download Apache NetBeans from [here](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html). The newest version is Apache NetBeans 11.0. You can read its features from [here](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/index.html). For this release no official installers are provided, You can download the binaries and unzip them.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the JDK is in the downloads folder.
Have you installed the JDK there or it is just the installation file?

If the latter - is it an executable or zip?

Essentially what I would recommend is to make sure you have installed the JDK first, has got JAVA_HOME environment variable configured and then re try netbeans installation again.